# CSS of anchor hover in ul and li

Tags: html, css

I have this navigation, It's working fine. But when I'm apply  tags in the li, the text hover, text color effect is just getting messy. I want to apply anchor styling in the css so the text styling remain same after after apply ahrefs.

***HTML***

```
<ul class="rexademenu"><li class="rexademenu">Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>
    Portfolio
    <ul class="rexadesubmenu">
      <li>Web Design</li>
      <li>Web Development</li>
      <li>Illustrations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

***CSS***

```
.rexademenu {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.rexademenu  li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.rexademenu > li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
.rexadesubmenu  {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.rexadesubmenu > li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
.rexadesubmenu > li:hover { background: #666; }
.rexademenu > li:hover .rexadesubmenu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oyp6qkyz/2/

Comment: What does messy mean?

Comment: Mean the "Home" text color is getting blue and underlined.
I want to define custom style for ahrefs in this particular ul and ui.

Comment: I don't see a blue/underlined `home` here

Comment: @Zia Irshad, it isn't here. What browser are you using?

Comment: Yeah because it's in my global style.css
ahref style is getting called from there.

Comment: the same @jordumus's experience, i am cheking in ff

Comment: http://rexade.com/testing/about-us/
I'm implementing it here. The sub-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your css like this:

**Css**

```
.rexademenu li a{
    color:#666666;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.rexademenu li a:hover, .rexademenu li:hover a{
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oyp6qkyz/3/)

Answer (score 0):

(answer derived from comments)

If you don't want underlining and blue color on the menu, you could add this to the css:

```
.rexademenu  li a, .rexademenu li a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #AAA;
}
.rexademenu li a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
}
```

You override the code in your global css-file with this.

Comment: It's working perfect. But what if i want to display the color dark gray and make it white on hover? Where i have to add that color styling?